# One drive for Business very slow

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have encountered a consistent issue when downloading straight from the Onedrive Business  website, using the Graph SDK as well as talking directly to the Graph rest APIs through httpclient calls in silverlight. When i download a large single file, it seems my download is limited/throttled to approx 1-2 MB/sec however when i download a folder , it processes a transform from multiple files to a zip, and then changes the download url from tenant to a temp server and the download of the corresponding zip file is very fast downloading at around the 18-24 Mb/sec range. the files we are downloading are very large and this basically makes our solution unusable. However it works perfectly talking to the dropbox , google drive and onedrive(old) apis. Not sure if this is an issue in graph api or onedrive for business ?

Comment: Hi Barry, when you say that it works perfectly with the onedrive(old) apis, which were you referring to?

Comment: HI Ryan , this was from my original api calls as was limited by availability in silverlight and tools so i was talking directly to the https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/ api urls as opposed to talking to the graph api.

Comment: Through our calls we are able to download our single files from onedrive at 10-12 mb/sec using the same code however just talking to the graph api and one drive for business the max we ever get is 1-2mb/sec

Comment: Just one last update .. i have tried it on a different tenant and got the same problem ..

Comment: That definitely is slower than I would expect. Are you located in the same geographic region as where the OneDrive for Business tenant is located?